# Can't add keyframe to material displacement node

Tags: materials, node-editor, displacement, ocean-simulation

I usually go into timeline, select the frame, then into my material node editor, hover the parameter i want to keyframe and press i. This works for the first keyframe, but when I try to input a second one, it just won't let me change the value anymore. regardless of which frame I am on.

Does this have to do with the fact that it is about displacement ? or did I untick something by accident ? I can still keyframe other materials

[image]

Context : I'm trying to make a big ocean loop. and so I have OceanA's and OceanB's baked displacement data that I want to fade in one another using the multiply node. 
I have tried handling the fade using the scale parameter of the ocean but this parameter does not bake so I can't use it effectively